# reduce string to compare

Tags: database, string, vb.net, compare

I would like to know the most effective way to compare long strings, having a database sql server, such as:

long string -> compare to-> 5,000 records in database

I happened to convert the records and the string to compare, using crc32, but I'm not sure if it would be a more efficient method

Comment: using CRC32 wont save anything at all - you'd still have to fetch the data for each row and calculate the CRC for it before you compare. What are you trying to do-  Comparing is almost always an intermediate step to something else.

Comment: @Plutonix Excuse me, do not explain me very well, what I meant was this:

I have an empty database, to which I will enter values, these values are long strings, before entering a new value I want to know first whether or not it already exists in the database, but being long strings, as records increase, the process takes a long time

Comment: Still, comparing is usually a step to something else.  If we knew *what* you were trying to do rather than just *how* you are trying to do something we could help better.   Thats said rather than CRC32, I would do a SHA hash

Comment: @Plutonix The only thing I want to know is, if reducing the length of a string would help me to make comparisons faster, I have a robot that explores thousands of URLs and I want to store them in a database so that I do not re-explore them in the future, that's why I thought of crc32, since it reduces the size of the string a lot, the url does not interest me to keep it in its original form.

Comment: @carlos you could keep a cache copy of the URL locally with the index of your DB. it would make it faster than querying the server every time.

Answer (score 0):

If u have a database,then u can go with a `DataTable`/`DataSet`/`DataReader`,let's assume u are using a `DataReader`

```
 Dim cmd as new SqlCommand("Select * from table",connectionstring)
 Dim dr as SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
 While dr.Read
 If dr(1).ToString = "MyString" Then
 ''''Something will happen
 End if
 End While
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other partially identifying fields you could check then make a new field of, perhaps the first 10 characters of the string. Make an index on this field and then take the first 10 characters of string to insert as a parameter. This should reduce the number of long comparisons you need to do. Of course my selection of 10 characters is arbitrary. You would select a number that you can see from your data that would reduce the number of rows returned significantly but be as small as possible.

```
Private Function OKayToInsert(stringToInsert As String) As Boolean
        Using connection As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Dim stringShort As String = stringToInsert.Substring(0, 10)
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand("Select LongString From StringTable Where NewShortField = @ShortString", connection)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ShorString", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = stringShort
                Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If reader.HasRows Then
                        While reader.Read
                            If stringToInsert = reader.GetString(0) Then
                                Return False
                            End If
                        End While
                        Return True
                    Else
                        Return True
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

Comment: Because the OP suggested the content is URLs, can use the first domain information (after the http?:// and before the first /) as a better set of characters - this has the hallmarks of setting up a hash-bucket for faster data access.

Comment: Yes, this code could be easily adapted to any substring.